# How to reassign a higher-scoped reference variable in a loop

Tags: rust

Suppose I have a `modify_vec()` function that takes a vector reference and returns a new vector. It doesn't really matter what it does so for the sake of example it will just append a given number.

```rust
fn modify_vec(v: &Vec<i64>, i: i64) -> Vec<i64> {
    let mut new_v = v.clone();
    new_v.push(i);
    new_v
}
```

Now, suppose I want to run this `modify_vec` a few times, I could do it like that:

```rust
fn main() {
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    println!("{:?}", run(&v)); // Outputs [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
}

fn run(v: &Vec<i64>) -> Vec<i64> {
    let new_1 = modify_vec(&v, 4);
    let new_2 = modify_vec(&new_1, 5);
    modify_vec(&new_2, 6)
}
```

Or I can do it like that

```rust
fn run(v: &Vec<i64>) -> Vec<i64> {
    let mut new_v = modify_vec(&v, 4);
    new_v = modify_vec(&new_v, 5);
    modify_vec(&new_v, 6)
}
```

However it would obviously be better to use a loop. The problem is that the `run` function starts with a reference of the vector, but it must declare a new owned variable to store the returned value of `modify_vec`. The only way I found to initialize that owned variable outside of the loop was doing a `.clone()`, like this.

```rust
fn run(v: &Vec<i64>) -> Vec<i64> {
    let mut new_v = v.clone();
    for i in 4..7 {
        new_v = modify_vec(&new_v, i);
    }
    new_v
}
```

But this seems "wasteful", as it is my understanding that it makes a deep copy. In the previous unlooped examples, it was not necessary to clone the vector prior to passing it to the first call to `modify_vec`.Is there a better way?

Comment: You could unroll the first iteration of the loop: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=df15387ae6e63bfd0533c195018d7ba0

Comment: You clone a lot of times; are you sure the first time matters? Have you benchmarked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`modify_vec` should take a `Vec` by value instead of a reference. Let the caller `clone` the `Vec` if it doesn't want to (or cannot) transfer ownership – do not impose the cost of a `clone` on all callers.

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    println!("{:?}", run(&v)); // Outputs [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
}

fn run(v: &Vec<i64>) -> Vec<i64> {
    let mut new_v = v.clone();
    for i in 4..7 {
        new_v = modify_vec(new_v, i);
    }
    new_v
}

fn modify_vec(mut v: Vec<i64>, i: i64) -> Vec<i64> {
    v.push(i);
    v
}
```

Perhaps the example is too contrived, but there is no need to clone any `Vec` at all:

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    println!("{:?}", run(v)); // Outputs [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    //                   ^ this could be replaced with `v.clone()`
    //                     if `v` needs to be used later
}

fn run(mut v: Vec<i64>) -> Vec<i64> {
    for i in 4..7 {
        v = modify_vec(v, i);
    }
    v
}

fn modify_vec(mut v: Vec<i64>, i: i64) -> Vec<i64> {
    v.push(i);
    v
}
```

Comment: Or better, to take a mutable reference.

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense. I thought making a function take a reference instead of a value was "nicer" to the caller and more "generalizable", but using a value and letting the caller clone or not makes sense. It still feels a little weird that something as benign as "adding a loop" requires rethinking function signatures, but I'll live with that ^^